# Run a task in an ansible role only if it has not run before or there is a version change

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I have a task that installs a package from yum which takes a while to run every time I run the playbook. What I would like to do is only run a task only if it has not run before or the specified version in the default variables has changed. Anyone know a way to do this?

**tasks/main.yml:**

```
---
- name: install package via yum
  yum:
    name: package-name
  when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat'
```

**defaults/main.yml**

```
---
package_version: 1.1.1
```

What should happen is that if I change the version number it should run the task or if I run it on a new machine it should run the task but if not skip over it straight away when I run the playbook.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: What should happen is that if I change the version number it should run the task or if I run it on a new machine it should run the task but if not skip over it straight away when I run the playbook.

A: It is possible to run [package_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_facts_module.html#package-facts-package-information-as-facts) and find out if `package_version` has already been installed. If not then install/upgrade/downgrade it. [Version Comparison](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#version-comparison) test might be helpful in writing such a condition.